# I added a hyperlink just now and can't see it

Tags: discussion, bug, design

Look at this: [How is sushi supposed to be eaten?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/66707/how-is-sushi-supposed-to-be-eaten/66710#66710), there is one hyperlink in the entire answer. If you can see it, your eyes are better than mine (which wouldn't take much).

They used to be red or orange, right? Or am I just getting very blind?

Comment: It's a more obvious red-orange when it's unclicked. The color after visiting is indeed really hard to see. And... on mobile it's blue, totally fine!

Comment: @Jefromi That would seem to me to be a pretty easy fix. Hyperlinks should be visible even if not on mobile or if they have been clicked, right?

Comment: As a temporary workaround until SE designers fix it, there are some fixes (CSS, or GreaseMonkey, or Chrome/FireFox add-ons) that change specific stiles on a site, including some SE specific ones, which an individual user can apply locally.

Comment: Tagging as bug - it might be low-priority (it only affects already-visited links, and isn't so bad if the anchor is longer) but it does affect usability a bit.

Comment: retagging/bumping - I'm finding visited links surprisingly difficult to see on my laptop screen either in really bright ambient light or with the screen dimmed a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The link is there, and it is a brownish-reddish-orange after being clicked. Not a very high contrast, but it is visible, and even better visible for people who haven't been there and clicked it yet.

This is a blown up version of the link after it has been clicked.

[image]

Comment: And I believe it was always this way, it's just even harder to see when it's such a short link. I double-checked a page [back in March on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20160325214353/http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/67709/why-use-onions-in-cooking) - the links are #855252 when visited, #C33A3A when not, just like today. (Of course, it's probably still worth making it higher contrast.)

Comment: I've brought it up to the exalted ones. I'll keep pushing at it.